# install ubuntu as a dual boot with windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have two 3 primary partitions (boot, windows 7 and an unallocated).  My Lenovo laptop has UEFI but windows is booting as bios.  I have  ubuntu 18.04 on a usb stick and it loads well but I'd like to do a install onto the HDD.  When I start the install with a / partition, a /home partition and a /swap partition I get to a point that it tells me I need an EFI partition.  Can't I get Ubuntu to install as in bios mode as well?  If so, how do I make that happen?  Everything I read is confusing to me.

Comment: Boot from the USB in BIOS mode and don't create any partitions manually. The installer will do all by itself.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI .

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Lenovo BIOs/UEFI settings (F1 at power up, or thinkvantage button), and look at the preferences for boot mode.  Lenovo allows booting both ways, but you select which you prefer when both are possible.  Select "legacy" before "UEFI" and your install media will boot in legacy mode, without needing an EFI partition.

---

In legacy mode, no EFI partition is needed -- ignore any suggestion to create one.  Your new partitions may all be logical partitions within the extended partition.  The installer should create them as needed in the free space.

Comment: In this case do I just ignore the "install EFI partition that the ubuntu install recommends?  If I do will both windows 7 and ubuntu boot as needed?

Comment: If the installer boots in bios mode, it shouldn't ask about EFI.